# dynamic email subject and body from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, string, eval

In my admin site, I want editable

Dynamic subject in database text.

```
mailer = MailTemplate.find_by_template_name('friend_request')
# mailer.subject = "#{@user.username} wants to be friend on site.com"
```

I have to use code like :

```
mail(:to => friend.email, :subject => mailer.subject) do |format|
  format.text { render :inline => nl2br(mailer.body) }
  format.html { render :inline => nl2br(mailer.body) }
end
```

Now, I found body is working properly with dynamic code. But `SUBJECT` is not working with 
`mailer.subject` for value like `"#{@user.username} wants to be friend on SportsPundit.com"`

Please suggest. I tried with `eval(mailer.subject)` as well.

Comment: are you sure you are saving correct subject in database?

Comment: @Salil YES,In console my subject shows  `"\#{@user.username} wants to be friend on SportsPundit.com"` If it would be without forward slash then it would have been parsed itself

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a different templating language so you're not exposing ruby to the user. Handlebars may be a good choice.

In your MailTemplate object, subject would be

```
"{{ user/username }} wants to be friend on site.com"
```

Then you would render it using handlebars-rails or some other lib, passing `@user` as `user` in the handlebars template. This is better for the average user to figure out, so they aren't looking at ruby.